# NLTK Confusion Matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk

I was trying to write confusion matrix from NLTK. 
I tried the following example it ran good.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.metrics import*
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> brown_a = nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents()[:300]
>>> def tag_list(tagged_sents):
    return [tag for sent in tagged_sents for (word, tag) in sent]

>>> tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(brown_a)
>>> gold = tag_list(brown_a)
>>> def apply_tagger(tagger, corpus):
    return [tagger.tag(nltk.tag.untag(sent)) for sent in corpus]
>>> test = tag_list(apply_tagger(tagger, brown_a)
>>> cm = nltk.ConfusionMatrix(gold, test)
>>> print cm.pretty_format(show_percents=False,values_in_chart=True,truncate=5,sort_by_count=True)
```

But if I give tesset as follows,

```
>>> tests=nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents()[300:400]
>>> test = tag_list(apply_tagger(tagger, tests))
>>> cm = nltk.ConfusionMatrix(gold, test)
```

is generating error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    cm = nltk.ConfusionMatrix(gold, test)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics\confusionmatrix.py", line 46, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Lists must have the same length.')
ValueError: Lists must have the same length.
```

Even I try to give the same length of testset as,

```
>>> test1=nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents()[700:1000]
>>> test = tag_list(apply_tagger(tagger, test1))
>>> cm = nltk.ConfusionMatrix(gold, test)
```

It is giving me same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    cm = nltk.ConfusionMatrix(gold, test)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics\confusionmatrix.py", line 46, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Lists must have the same length.')
ValueError: Lists must have the same length.
>>>
```

If anybody may kindly help how may I absolve it?

Comment: I think it's referring to a mismatch in length relative to your gold set, print the  length of both lists. Also, gold isn't defined in your example code above.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have included gold now. Most likely even with same length I am getting error.

Comment: Well, for the error generating examples, example 1 you have len(test) = 2459 and len(gold) = 6642 and example 2 you have len(test) = 6261, which is different from gold.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It helped. I checked the quoted previous post that helped me in analyzing confusion matrix perhaps better than NLTK book, but my question asked a simple question happening to execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of ConfusionMatrix

```
def __init__(self, reference, test, sort_by_count=False):
    """
    Construct a new confusion matrix from a list of reference
    values and a corresponding list of test values.

    :type reference: list
    :param reference: An ordered list of reference values.
    :type test: list
    :param test: A list of values to compare against the
        corresponding reference values.
    :raise ValueError: If ``reference`` and ``length`` do not have
        the same length.
    """
    if len(reference) != len(test):
        raise ValueError('Lists must have the same length.')
```

http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/metrics/confusionmatrix.html

I'm not going to go through your code since it's been a while since I used NLTK, but just try printing your gold standard, prediction arrays and make sure they are of same length

Answer (score 0):

For both error generating examples, you have length mismatches as the error states:

- Example 1: len(test) = 2459 and len(gold) = 6642
- Example 2: len(test) = 6261, and len(gold) = 6642

You could perhaps trim gold via something like:

```
gold_full = tag_list(brown_a)
gold = gold_full[:len(test)]
```

With the assumption gold standard will also be bigger than the test; otherwise you can add if condition?